# Python web scraping with beautifulsoup - can't extract Principal Investigator from Clinicaltrials.gov

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, export-to-csv

(Disclaimer: I'm a Python and web scraping noob, but I'm doing my best to learn).

I'm trying to extract 3 key data points from research studies on clinicaltrials.gov.  They have an API, but the API doesn't capture the things I need.  I want to get a (1) short description of the study, (2) the Principal Investigator (PI), and (3) some keywords associated with the study.  I believe my code captures 1 and 3, but not 2.  I can't seem to figure out why I'm not getting the Principal Investigator(s) name. Here are the two sites I have in my code:

https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03530579
https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03436992

Here's my code (I know the PI code is wrong, but I wanted to demonstrate that I tried) :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv   

fields=['PI','Project_Summary', 'Keywords']
with open(r'test.csv', 'a') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerow(fields)

urls = ['https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03436992','https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03530579']
for url in urls:

     response = requests.get(url)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
     #get_keywords
     for rows in soup.find_all("td"):
          k = rows.get_text()     
          Keywords = k.strip()
     #get Principal Investigator   
     PI = soup.find_all('padding:1ex 1em 0px 0px;white-space:nowrap;')

     #Get description    
     Description = soup.find(class_='ct-body3 tr-indent2').get_text()
     d = {'Summary2':[PI,Description,Keywords]} 

     df = pd.DataFrame(d)
     print (df)
     import csv   
     fields=[PI,Description, Keywords]
     with open(r'test.csv', 'a') as f:
          writer = csv.writer(f)
          writer.writerow(fields)
```

Comment: I managed to get the PI, but I don't see keywords getting picked up either. What are the keywords you're trying to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use the following selector

i.e. `PI = soup.select_one('.tr-table_cover [headers=name]').text`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
urls = ['https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03530579', 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03436992','https://clinicaltrials.gov/show/NCT03834376']
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        item = soup.select_one('.tr-table_cover [headers=name]').text if soup.select_one('.tr-table_cover [headers=name]') is not None else 'No PI'
        print(item)
```

The `.` is a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) and the `[]` is an [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector. The space between is a [`descendant combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) specifying that the element retrieved on the right is a child of that on the left

Comment: Thank you, all! I used QHarr's code and for the most part this worked. However, when I add a clinicaltrials.gov URL and there is no PI listed, I get a "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text" error. How could I get around this?

Comment: I'll edit for you. Can you provide the current failing url so I can add to code

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I simply used pandas to get the tables. this will return a list of dataframes. You could then just iterate through those to look for the PI:

```
tables = pd.read_html(url)
for table in tables:
    try:
        if 'Principal Investigator' in table.iloc[0,0]:
            pi =  table.iloc[0,1]
    except:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are many ways to walk down the DOM tree and your way is very "brittle". Meaning that your chosen selectors from which to begin your search are extremely specific and bound to CSS styling which can change far easier than the structure of the document as a whole.

But if I were you I'd being filtering down some nodes on some criteria and then focus on that specific group while you sift through the noise.

So looking at those urls that you showed it appears the data is structured neatly and using tables. Based on that we can make some assumptions like

1. It is data that is inside a table
2. It will contain the "principal investigator" string inside of it

```
# get all the tables in the page
tables = soup.find_all('table')
# now filter down to a smaller set of tables that might contain the info
refined_tables = [table for table in tables if 'principal investigator' in str(table).lower()]
```

At this point we have a strong candidate in our `refined_tables` list that might actually contain our primary table and is ideally of size 1 assuming the "principal investigator" filter we used isn't anywhere else inside other tables.

```
principal_investigator = [ele for ele in refined_tables.findAll('td') if 'name' in ele.attrs['headers']][0].text
```

Right here what was done from looking at the site was that they are using the attribute `headers` to assign the role of the `td` tag within the table row.

So in essence, just think of it from a top level and start narrowing down things as much as possible in simple steps to help you find what you're looking for.